# Problem with alpha transparency in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a .csv file, `test1.csv` that looks like this:

```
seed,rate,TYPE,SUFFIX
1,1,A,Sim
1,1,A,Ana
2,1,A,Ana
2,2,A,Ana

1,1,B,Sim
1,1,B,Ana
2,1,B,Ana
2,2,B,Ana

1,1,C,Sim
2,2,C,Ana
```

I want to set `alpha = 1` for `rate = 1` and 
`alpha = 0` for `rate = 2`

I have the following R code:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)
require(dplyr)


pdf(file="sweep_feasibility-vs-injection_test.pdf", height=3, width=6)

a<-read.csv('./test1.csv',header=T);
a$alphayr <- as.factor(ifelse(a$rate == 1, TRUE, FALSE))

a<-na.omit(a)
p<-ggplot(a,aes(x=rate,group=factor(SUFFIX))) +
    geom_bar(stat="count", position = "dodge", aes(fill=factor(SUFFIX), alpha=alphayr))+
        scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0,1), guide = F) +
    facet_grid(~TYPE)+
    xlab('Injection Rate (%)') +
    ylab('Feasible (%)');

p + theme_bw() %+replace% theme(axis.title=element_text(),axis.title.y=theme_bw()$axis.title.y) +
    theme(
      axis.line=element_line(color='black'),
      legend.position="top",
      legend.background=element_rect(fill="transparent"),
      axis.title.x = element_text(size=15),
      axis.title.y = element_text(size=15),
      panel.border=element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
      legend.key.width=unit(0.5,"cm"),
      legend.key.height=unit(0.5,"cm"),
      plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
      legend.key = element_rect(colour = "black", size=0.1),
      legend.title=element_text(size=10),
      axis.text.y=element_text(size=15,color='black'),
      axis.text.x=element_text(angle=0,hjust=0.5, size=15, color='black'),
      legend.text=element_text(size=15))+
guides(
       fill=guide_legend(nrow=1,title=""),
       color=guide_legend(nrow=1,title=""),
       shape=guide_legend(nrow=1,title="")
       );
```

when I run this code, I get the following graph:

[image]

I don't understand why I am seeing a bar for `rate = 2`

Comment: Could you please edit your code to make it minimal and reproducible? It's hard to pick out the code relevant to your question about alpha amidst all of the irrelevant theme edits. See [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and [mcve]

Comment: It is reproducible. I am running it on Linux. and I have the data in test1.csv given at the top.

Comment: Why do you load all this packages if you only need to use `ggplot2`?

Comment: actually I have other data in my R code that I haven't shared. That data require those packages but for this problem they are irrelevant. You are right, I should have deleted the packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this is `group = factor(SUFFIX)` which, I think, isn't really a relevant aesthetic for `geom_bar` at all. Erasing that gives

[image]